# CodeIgniter Disallowed Key Characters

Tags: codeigniter

CodeIgniter is giving me a `Disallowed Key Characters` error. I've narrowed it down to the name attribute of a form field: `name='prod[50-4121.5]'` but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Comment: Can you post code? Is it from a form?

Comment: This also may affect Expression Engine < 2, and may be caused by browser toolbars. Just found this out when a "MindSpark" toolbar (whatever that is) was setting it's own cookies on a user's computer. Moral of the story: Don't install third-party toolbars.

Comment: whether 50-4121.5 is a field name

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The problem is you are using characters not included in the standard Regex. Use this:

**`!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}\:\;\.\,\?\!\@\#\$%\^\*\"\~\'+=\\\ &_\/\.\[\]-\}\{]+$/iu", $str)`**

As per the comments (and personal experience) you should not modify they `Input.php` file — rather, you should create/use your own `MY_Input.php` as follows:

```
<?php

class MY_Input extends CI_Input {

    /**
     * Clean Keys
     *
     * This is a helper function. To prevent malicious users
     * from trying to exploit keys we make sure that keys are
     * only named with alpha-numeric text and a few other items.
     * 
     * Extended to allow: 
     *      - '.' (dot), 
     *      - '[' (open bracket),
     *      - ']' (close bracket)
     * 
     * @access  private
     * @param   string
     * @return  string
     */
    function _clean_input_keys($str) {
        // UPDATE: Now includes comprehensive Regex that can process escaped JSON
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\:\;\.\,\?\!\@\#\$%\^\*\"\~\'+=\\\ &_\/\.\[\]-\}\{]+$/iu", $str)) {
            /**
             * Check for Development enviroment - Non-descriptive 
             * error so show me the string that caused the problem 
             */
            if (getenv('ENVIRONMENT') && getenv('ENVIRONMENT') == 'DEVELOPMENT') {
                var_dump($str);
            }
            exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
        }

        // Clean UTF-8 if supported
        if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE) {
            $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
        }

        return $str;
    }

}

// /?/> /* Should never close php file - if you have a space after code, it can mess your life up */
```

---

### ++Chinese Character Support

```
// NOTE: \x{4e00}-\x{9fa5} = allow chinese characters
// NOTE: 'i' — case insensitive
// NOTE: 'u' — UTF-8 mode
if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}\:\;\.\,\?\!\@\#\$%\^\*\"\~\'+=\\\ &_\/\.\[\]-\}\{]+$/iu", $str) { ... }

// NOTE: When Chinese characters are provided in a URL, they are not 'really' there; the browser/OS
//   handles the copy/paste -> unicode conversion, eg:
//        一二三  -->  xn--4gqsa60b   
//   'punycode' converts these codes according to RFC 3492 and RFC 5891.
//   https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js ---  $ bower install punycode
```

Comment: Upvoting the more elegant solution.  Or you can remove the `preg_match` entirely.  I'm not aware of any inherent security vulnerabilities that this might open.

Comment: Where should I place this file?

Comment: You should be able to create a `MY_Input.php` file in a Core Folder (or wherever your `My_*` files are - I have modified my Codeigniter Instance for security purposes.)

Comment: Ok, so I manage to override the function '_clean_input_keys($str)' placing the file MY_Input.php into application/core/, however I can't go thru when I'm processing the form. @Wallter, the format of my fields are name[number], because I can change de amount of fields dynamically. Do I need to do something else? Thanks!

Comment: This is great.I just change my span html 0.0 t 0 and it worked

Answer (score 27):

Open `libraries/Input.php` (`system/core/Input.php` in CI version 2.0+) and locate `function _clean_input_keys($str){`, The whole block should look like so:

```
function _clean_input_keys($str)
{
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Modify the PCRE sot that it allows the new chars.

Please not that the char thats missing is the `.`(dot) and you should always escape the `.`(dot) in Regular Expressions as they will otherwise allow any single char.

```
/^[a-z0-9:_\/-\.]+$/i
```

Comment: Sorry for the double posting.

Comment: The line in the config/config.php file relates to characters permitted in a url.

Comment: `permitted_uri_chars` has nothing to do with this, so I've removed that piece from your answer since it was confusing other people.

Comment: This was a while back, But I am sure I tested that.

Comment: I did what you said now there is Disallowed Key Characters all over my site... need help

Comment: Remember to create MY_Input class to extend CI_Input class. DON'T hardcode anything there. [Read this](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html).

Comment: @machineaddict OK, but _clean_input_keys is a private method, how can I override a private method on my own MY_Input?

Comment: @rubdottocom: as I see in CodeIgniter 2.1.3, the method `_clean_input_keys` is not declared as private in `CI_Input` class and therefore you can extend this method in `MY_Input` without any problems.

Answer (score 9):

To use CodeIgniter with jQuery Ajax, use "Object" as data instead of Query string as below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: site_url + "ajax/signup",
    data: ({'email': email, 'password': password}), //<--- Use Object
    type: "post",
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        $('#sign-up').html(response);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log("The following error occured: "+
                    textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've been searching for hours trying to find why my posted data wouldn't return any of the PHP headers. Thank you for this answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
function _clean_input_keys($str)
{
if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
{
exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
}

return $str;
}
```

Please add .$str to exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
Like: exit('Disallowed Key Characters. '.$str);

to help you in your search for rogue errors.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error after I posted a form of mine.
I simply missed the opening quote in one of my input name attributes. I had:

`<input name=first_name">`

Fixing that got rid of the error.

Answer (score 3):

Step1. Search for function _clean_input_keys on /system/core/Input.php

Step2. Modify this line

exit(‘Disallowed Key Characters.’);

to

exit(‘Disallowed Key Characters.’ . $str);

Step3. Refresh page to see the characters which generate the error

Step4. If you need to add those characters into the exception list, just add to this line

> if ( ! preg_match(“/^[a-z0-9:_/-]+$|/i”, $str))

I add | (pipe) character on the example above

Answer (score 2):

Php will evaluate what you wrote between the [] brackets.

```
$foo = array('eins', 'zwei', 'apples', 'oranges');
var_dump($foo[3-1]);
```

Will produce `string(6) "apples"`, because it returns $foo[2].

If you want that as a string, put inverted commas around it.

Comment: Codeigniter filters the URI for a specific traditional set of characters, you have to 'permit' now chars if you want them to be passed, and the the `QUERY_STRING` is not the same as `GPC` so there parsed differently.

Comment: @RobertPitt haha, I still don't really get his question ;)

Comment: when you go `http://site.com/controller/[a][b]` it strikes an error because CI found a `[` and `]` which are not permitted by default :)

Comment: @RobertPitt Oh, I get your comment, just didn't think the question had anything to do with URIs ;) But then again the question was a bit short anyways.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when sending data from a rich text editor where I had included an ampersand.  Replacing the ampersand with %26 - the URL encoding of ampersand - solved the problem.  I also found that a jQuery ajax request configured like this magically solves the problem:

```
request = $.ajax({
        "url": url,
        type: "PUT",
        dataType: "json",
        data: json
    });
```

where the object `json` is, surprise, surprise, a JSON object containing a property with a value that contains an ampersand.

Comment: Thank you!, i was working with curl and adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Content-Type: application/json"));` , which is the equivalent of `dataType:"json"`, solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Open `libraries/Input.php` (`system/core/Input.php` in `CI version 2.0+`) and locate function `_clean_input_keys($str){`,

Modify `if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))` to `if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\-|]+$/i", $str))`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem thanks to french specials characters. Here is my class in case anybody needs it. It has to be saved here : /application/core/MY_Input.php

*(also this extension will report witch character is not allowed in the future)*

```
class MY_Input extends CI_Input {
```

`function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
* Clean Keys
*
* This is a helper function. To prevent malicious users
* from trying to exploit keys we make sure that keys are
* only named with alpha-numeric text and a few other items.
*
* @access   private
* @param    string
* @return   string
*/
function _clean_input_keys($str)
{
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-àâçéèêëîôùû]+$/i", $str))
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters : '.$str);
    }

    // Clean UTF-8 if supported
    if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
    {
        $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
    }

    return $str;
}`

}

Read The Friendly Manual about core classes extension : http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error after I posted a form of mine. they have a space in to my input name attributes. input name='    first_name'

Fixing that got rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i was serializing an input form using jquery serialize() and then urlencoding it using encodeURIComponent().

```
var datas = form.serialize();
encodeURIComponent(datas);
$.getJSON(url,datas,function(){});
```

and codeigniter was giving the disallowed character error.

i figured the issue here was, jquery serialize gives an encoded output and i was again encoding it with the encodeURIcomponent which was unnecessary, and when codeingiter decoded it it was not getting the actual string as some part was encoded twice. 
i will explain it with an example.

```
string: quantity[]=1&option=sell

urlencoded while serializing: quantity%5B%5D%3D1%26option%3Dsell

again urlencoded with encodedURICompontent(): quantity%255B%255D%253D1%2526option%253Dsell
```

---at codeigntier

```
urldecode: quantity%5B%5D=1&option=sell
```

which has disallowed charecters as per the input class regex.

note: this is not an answer to this question, but would help to check if one is encountering this error...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, you can solve the problem by clearing the cookies of your browser. I had the same problem and solved it this way.

Comment: if one is using http://localhost, and switching between several frameworks/languages locally, then this should be the first thing to check.

Answer (score 1):

Took a while to figure this one out. Seems most of us missed the obvious error…the last “-” is not escaped.

Adding the . and | as I’ve seen other suggest may work for you, but the regex was supposed to be:

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/\-\.|]+$/i", $str))
```

Answer (score 1):

i saw this error when i was trying to send a form, and in one of the fields' names, i let the word "endereço".

```
echo form_input(array('class' => 'form-control', 'name' => 'endereco', 'placeholder' => 'Endereço', 'value' => set_value('endereco')));
```

When i changed 'ç' for 'c', the error was gone.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue but my problem was that I by mistake added a space before the name of the input like so:

```
<input type="text" name=" evening_time_phone">
```

When it shpuld be like this:

```
<input type="text" name="evening_time_phone">
```

Answer (score 0):

The error I referenced was generated in system/libraries/Input.php (about line 215 - look for function _clean_input_keys($str).

The regex there does not allow for the dot character in an index.  I changed it so it would.

Comment: This is now in system/core/Input.php

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I've found it is in domain name of the email address which is somehow changed from `.` to `_` like: `name@domain_com` instead `name@domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it could be caused by uncompleted syntax, like :

```
$('#teks').val
```

instead of

```
$('#teks').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below Code in the _clean_input_keys function

```
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$|/i", $str))
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.\n');
    }
    if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
    {
        $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
    }

    return $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases when you have a existing software and you are trying to deploy in a new enviroment this kind of error should be caused by the PHP property

```
short_open_tag
```

Check if you have enabled in your new enviroment.
In other words PHP couldn't read the  tags in your code.