# CodeIgniter - disallowed key characters

Tags: codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter Disallowed Key Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters)

I have a bit of an issue with a form I'm trying to submit, its dynamic and the checkbox values come from the database, only problem is that one of the fields has a `#` and when I try to submit the form, it returns `'disallowed key characters'`.

How do i make it ok to submit a `#` ?

Comment: Can you show us your code for this field?

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="-c#" class="radio" value="A" />

Comment: What if you rename it to `"-csharp"` ?

Comment: works perfect if i rename it to that, the only problem is that im building this system for a client, and they entered the c# so i kind of have to make it future proof :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per your question it seems that you are using get as a method in the form and because of that it is giving `disallowed key characters` error.

To allow the character # just add it in the following in your [CONFIG](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html) file -

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '\#';
```

And now the character # will be allowed in the url.

Comment: I tried adding that to the default line that ships with CI so it ended up as $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-\#'; ... But that didnt seem to work

Answer (score 9):

It's hardcoded into the Input class in the function _clean_input_keys().

Just create a MY_Input class and override the function.

```
/**
* Clean Keys
*
* This is a helper function. To prevent malicious users
* from trying to exploit keys we make sure that keys are
* only named with alpha-numeric text and a few other items.
*
* @access   private
* @param    string
* @return   string
*/
function _clean_input_keys($str)
{
    // if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str)) <---- DEL
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[#a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str)) // <----INS
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
    }

    // Clean UTF-8 if supported
    if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
    {
        $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

replace :

```
      if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
```

with this :

```
      if ( ! preg_match("/^[#a-z0-9:_|\/-]+$/i", $str))
```

in `system/core/input.php`

Comment: do not override core files. it breaks upgrades