# "Disallowed Key Character" error in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter Disallowed Key Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters)

When I check all the checkboxes (code below) it gives me this error:

> Disallowed Key Character

Here's my HTML:

```
<label>Stability Control </label><input type="checkbox" class="largercheckbox"   name="checkBox[Stability-Control]"></input><br/>
<label>Xenon Headlamps</label><input type="checkbox" class="largercheckbox" name="checkBox[Xenon-Headlamps]"></input><br/>
```

What's the problem here? I think my config file permits those characters:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Comment: I just cleared my cookies and it worked!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following function found in `system/core/Input.php` disallows the characters.

```
function _clean_input_keys($str) {
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str)) ...
```

This will allow a-z A-Z 0-9 : _ \ / -

You should extend the Input class by creating a MY_Input.php file in `/application/core/` and recreate the method and add any characters you wish to allow. See [Creating Core System Classes](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html) for an example as to how to achieve this.

However you should be careful with this as you could open up unnecessary security holes. You are better off rewriting your form so that it passes the existing validation.

Edit: [This article](http://www.snaver.net/2010/01/17/disallowed-key-characters-codeigniter-error/) describes both the problem and a solution as described above by extending the Input class.

Having searched, the following posts also demonstrate how this is accomplished to solve the same issue

- [CodeIgniter Disallowed Key Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters)
- [CodeIgniter - disallowed key characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423212/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters)

Comment: No the form method is post, i don't think so

Comment: Apologies, I misinterpreted your question as you mentioned `permitted_uri_chars` which led me to not really read the error message properly. This comes from the Input class rather than the config.php file

Comment: Ok thanks for enlighten me with this, i knew what i had to do

Comment: i didn't give you downvote, i gave up upvote and choose your answer as accepted answer, thanks again

Comment: No problem glad I could help. I was just asking whoever did downvote why so that I could improve my answer if necessary. Ben

Answer (score 7):

Ok here is my answer

You have to go first to system/core/Input.php and look for a function called

```
_clean_input_keys($str)
```

I was don't know what is the character that is disallowed here so when you add the **$str** like the following

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.'.$str);  // HERE
    }
```

you will get exactly the character that cause the problem **mine was ' ) '** so you have to do one of the following remove the disallowed character from the html or permit it like @Ben Swinburne said

Hope that help others