# codeigniter preg_match throws Disallowed characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, preg-match

Simple line in Codeigniter that worked before, now throws Dissallowed Key Character error.. In core/Input.php

```
function _clean_input_keys($str)
{
if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-@]+$/i", $str)) 
   exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
}
```

It fails due to a dash sign in **blah-12-345**... It worked fine before, but why it fails now???
Thanks

Comment: Plz check this link.. It could help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114512/disallowed-key-character-error-in-codeigniter

Comment: Also this one too
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters

Comment: Great, thanks. It looks the same, but as soon as @ appears at the end of the string - it goes banana... Should I swap dash and @ places...?