# Disallowed key characters while uploading image in base64 format

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I'm developing Windows phone(8.0)apps and I'm new to it,I'm using below code to post image to server in `Base64` format using post client

```
Uri uri = new Uri(UPLOAD_IMAGE_PATH);
UploadImageData requestData = new UploadImageData();
requestData.image = base64String;
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData);
PostClient proxy = new PostClient(jsonString);
proxy.DownloadStringCompleted += new PostClient.DownloadStringCompletedHandler(proxy_DownloadStringCompleted);
proxy.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

where `base64String` is my image string encoded in Bae64 by using below code

```
internal static string ImageToBase64String(Stream choosenPhoto,Image image)
{
   WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)image.Source);
   byte[] byteArray;
   using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
   {
     bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
     byteArray = stream.ToArray();
     return Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray); 
   }           
}
```

In below response it returns "`disallowed key charaters`" on `result`.

```
void proxy_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, WindowsPhonePostClient.DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   string result = e.Result;
}
```

But when i post same JSON string using `REST Client` from Mozilla, JSON response from server is successfull.
I searched about this and i got some links [link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114512/disallowed-key-character-error-in-codeigniter), [link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423212/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters) that i need to allow characters on server side in `Input.php` file, So exactly what kind of character i need to allow. It works from `REST Client` did i miss something in my C# code, Please help me

Comment: You really really shouldn't post a image as a base64 encoded string in a json request. Instead use a POST request with the binary data, and the .NET API will handle the conversion itself.

Comment: Thanks Claus, but API's are developed in PHP and i do not have any control on that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to explicitly mention the Base64 string (unless I'm missing something, having never developed for a WinPhone OS). Have you checked the URL that you're sending a POST request to?