# Disallowed Key Characters CodeIgniter Error

Tags: codeigniter, escaping

I'm having this error "Disallowed Key Characters." I have try to resolve this, by debugging input.php file. I have this output as

Disallowed Key Characters.2548_don't

can anyone tell me, how to escape single quote

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter - disallowed key characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423212/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters)

Comment: Thats not working for single quote.. do understand

Comment: Have you tried... $this->db->escape() ?

Comment: Post your code where you were getting it

Comment: while posting this value  "2548_don't"  to controller, im getting that error

Answer (score 0):

Try This

Go to application -> config -> config.php

And try to find

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars']
```

change it to

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '\#';
```

this # will allow all the characters.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9':_\/-]+$/i", $str))
     {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.'.$str);
     }
```

added single quote in preg match and it is working now

Thanks

Comment: The occurs if the input field _name_ has characters, that are not supported/allowed in the `preg_match`.