# codeigniter Disallowed Key Characters error

Tags: php, sql, forms, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter Disallowed Key Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters)

Im trying to have a form submit to a controller were it is then inserted into a database. It worked for the past couple days but apparently i accidentally changed something because it "randomly" doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated as i couldn't figure it out after searching online. Thanks!

PHP

```php
 public function    houses () {
if ($this->input->post()) {
    $bedrooms = $this->input->post('bedrooms');
    $bathrooms = $this->input->post('bathrooms');
    $street = $this->input->post('street');
    $house_number = $this->input->post('house_number');
    $basement = $this->input->post('basement');
    $garage = $this->input->post('garage');
    $fence = $this->input->post('fence');

    $query = $this->db->query('INSERT INTO houses VALUES (NULL, "'.
         $bedrooms.'","'.$bathrooms.'","'.$house_number.'","'.
         $street.'","'.$basement.'","'.$garage.'","'.$fence.'")');
}

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM houses");

foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    $data['bedrooms'] = $row->bedrooms; $data['bathrooms'] = $row->bathrooms;
    $data['house_number'] = $row->house_number;
    $data['street'] = $row->street; $data['garage'] = $row->garage;
    $data['basement'] = $row->basement; $data['fence'] = $row->fence;
    $data['id'] = $row->id;

    $this->data['houses'][] = $data;
}

$title = 'Houses';
$this->data['title'] = $title;
$this->template->add_css('css/dog.css');
$this->template->write_view('content', 'houses', $this->data);
$this->template->render();
 }
```

HTML

```html
<form method='post' action='<?php site_url('welcome/houses')?>'>
  <li><span>Bedrooms</span>
    <input type="text" name="be stdClass::$emaildrooms" /></li>
  <li><span>Bathrooms</span>
    <input type="text" name="bathrooms" /></li>
  <li><span>House Number</span>
    <input type="text" name="house_number" /></li>
  <li><span>Street</span>
    <input type="text" name="street" /></li>
 <li>
   <span>Basement</span>
   <select name="basement">
     <option>Yes</option>
     <option>No</option>
   </select><br/>
 </li>
 <li>
   <span>Garage</span>
   <select name="garage">
     <option>Yes</option>
     <option>No</option>
   </select><br/>
 </li>
 <li>
   <span>Fence</span>
   <select name="fence">
     <option>Yes</option>
     <option>No</option>
   </select><br/>
 </li>
 <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
<input type="text" name="be stdClass::$emaildrooms" />
```

`be stdClass::$emaildrooms` contains characters that Codeigniter does not allow in input keys.

It looks like a mistake anyways, as if `stdClass::$email` snuck in somehow - maybe while you did a massive search/replace in your files.

Comment: That's a good one, isn't it? ;)