# CodeIgniter with Firefox and Disallowed Key Characters

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, browser

Recently I downloaded codeIgniter 2.1.1.
I droped the CI files on my wamp on windows 7, After that simply I opened up firefox and type localhost and I saw this message **"Disallowed Key Characters"**
But, I do not have this problem with Chrome and Opera.

Comment: Did you try to use google ? First result: http://tiffanybbrown.com/2010/07/21/codeigniters-disallowed-key-characters-error-revisited/

Comment: Have you tried removing your cookies?

Comment: The newest version is 2.1.2 which is a bug fix release, you may be encountering this bug

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is this code in `system/core/Input.php` on line 728:

```
<?php 
/**
    * Clean Keys
    *
    * This is a helper function. To prevent malicious users
    * from trying to exploit keys we make sure that keys are
    * only named with alpha-numeric text and a few other items.
    *
    * @access   private
    * @param    string
    * @return   string
    */
function _clean_input_keys($str)
{
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
    }

    // Clean UTF-8 if supported
    if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
    {
        $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
    }

    return $str;
}
?>
```

It checks the keys in key=>value pairs eg: example.com?key=value if your key is not within the range of `a-z0-9:_/-` it will throw that error.

Change `exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');`

to `exit('Disallowed Key Characters.'.$str);` to give you an idea about what key is at fault. Remember this perhaps is checking cookies through `$_REQUEST/$_COOKIE` so its also a good idea to clear your cookies, perhaps from an older script or version on the same path.

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks , I do have another question, I wanna upload my files on the internet, Will every firefox has this problem?(I mean, the people who uses FF)

Comment: Uploading should not be a problem (dont trouble trouble till trouble troubles you) ;p No once you assign proper correct code, eg no illegal chars you should be fine. Thx for the accept.

Comment: p.s. you should NEVER edit the core files - always extend them with your changes instead

Comment: Thanks for pointing out at the cookie .. there was a cookie with name set as http://*_sdcbjhsbdjc_csdcb which was failing the preg_match ..

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in your browser cookies. I found this entry in mine

```
'instance0|ab'
```

Maybe its in your browser. Delete all your cookies and make sure they are gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I cleared all the cookie and then relaunch.  Site worked correctly.  It may happen because of poorly formed cookie.  Hopefully it helps someone..

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error!

There is the code in system/core/Input.php on line 729.

Just adding a '.' and '|' will allow to pass:

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/\-\.|]+$/i", $str))
```

This worked for me on my windows localhost with a sub-directory setup :)