# Disallowed Key Characters when doing an AJAX POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CodeIgniter Disallowed Key Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters)

I'm using CodeIgniter and when I do a `POST` of a `<textarea>` using an AJAX call through jQuery, I get a `Disallowed Key Characters` error and I don't know why. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: This link might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem with CodeIgniter and found a solution here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/140333/. It involves either making changes to `system/libraries/Input.php` in CodeIgniter or removing characters forbidden by the regular expression.

These lines are where the error message originates:

```
if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
{
    exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
}
```

Comment: i got solution but too risk, i change the input.php in libraries then i remark the pattern regexp, but still the problem