# CodeIgniter : Disallowed key Characters in Chrome

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter and I'm getting the following error:

```
Disallowed Key Characters.
```

This only happens in Chrome. I've tried it in Firefox and it is working well.
I don't use cookies, character `#`, or method "get".

I need help how to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: show me your url that problem

Comment: It still in localhost..... :'(

Comment: @user3769430 Provide local url

Comment: I mean your url I just want look string of the uri request

Comment: how it could be? Sorry, I'm beginner

Comment: Oh sory. I think you want to see my website.
Localhost/MT_Superadmin/index.php/Superadmin

Comment: possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter Disallowed Key Characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters)

Comment: I'm sorry, what the meaning of duplicate?

Answer (score 2):

To allow the character # just add it in the following in your CONFIG file -

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = '\#';
```

And now the character # will be allowed.

Comment: provide me ur URl please

Comment: there might be problem with underScore in ur url
/MT_Superadmin/index.php

Comment: but I always use it. Before, I'd finishing my first project using CodeIgniter without same problem. and its url : localhost/MT_Gudang/index.php/index.php.

Comment: It's solved. You're right. I try to delete underScore and it's success running! :D :D :D
Thanks

Comment: The `#` character has special meaning and is never send to the server. It does not make any sense making it an allowed character.