# browser's cookies causing Dissalowed key character in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url, jquery-jtable

sorry because I had asking the same question before. here is the url [CodeIgniter : Disallowed key Characters in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25599724/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters-in-chrome).

I was solving the problem by deleting _ (underScore) in URL. at that time, the problem was solved. later, CodeIgniter give me a Disallowed Key Characters error again and always. I had asking this question in a PHP group in Indonesia, and someone gives me solution that I must delete the cookies in my browser. when I delete the cookies, my application is working well. But several days later, the error is comeback again. Then, I delete the cookies again. It happens over and over again. I don't know what is the point causing this error. For information, I'm using jquery Jtable plugin. I don't know what the relation between this error and jtable plugin but it is first time happen when I was implementing jtable plugin in my application. Anyone have any ideas what I can do to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues like you and spend much time trying to fix it.

The problem is because of the Jtable as it appends a # in the cookie name which is not allowed by codeigniter for some reason.

You require a minor modification to jTable's Javascript function *generateCookieKeyPrefix: function () to replace '#' in the cookie name prefix with '*'.

the function _generateCookieKeyPrefix: function () can be found in the jtables js file default name jquery.jtables.js

Hope this answer is useful for you.

Comment: yes you're right. I solved this but I solved it by editing file input.php in library folder to allow '#' character in the url of Codeigniter.

Comment: yeah that's also a solution to it. nice that you sorted it out :)

Answer (score -1):

[did you check which character give you this message ?](https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/235259/#1067410)  This can help you to identify the cause .

Comment: if it is because some character, why my application working well after I'm deleting the cookies of browser?

Comment: follow my previous link . In the system/codeigniter/system/core/input.php file . change exit(‘Disallowed Key Characters.’); to  exit(‘Disallowed Key Characters.’. $str);

Comment: now I find what character causing this problem.
Disallowed Key Characters.jtable#-472140088page-size

Comment: Now I get it, thank you very much..... :D
this is can solve it.
function _clean_input_keys($str)
 {
  if ( ! preg_match("/^[#a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
  {
   exit('Disallowed Key Characters.'.$str);
  }

  // Clean UTF-8 if supported
  if (UTF8_ENABLED === TRUE)
  {
   $str = $this->uni->clean_string($str);
  }

  return $str;
 }