# Url make an error in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url

I am using codeigniter ,Client try to take the site using http://www.example.com , It shows `"Disallowed character error "`.But No issues in my browser, the error only shows in client's system. 
I got some answer , but it not working for me.

```
Ref Link : http://wejn.com/blog/2014/10/hunting-down-the-codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters-error/

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters
```

Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the disallowed charters  into your `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` it could be that you are missing few charters `a-z 0-9~%\.\:_\-&=$`

First: copy this`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%\.\:_\-&=$';` into your config.php

Second: **Stop** and **Start** local host if on xampp or wamp / lamp etc refresh page.