# Disallowed key character in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a view page.i have to edit a list of values.bt after submit i have an error disallowed character key.I cant find it how this error occur.

**view**

```
foreach($track_details->result() as $name) { ?>  
    <form  class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="income_edit" action="<?php echo base_url();?>income_list_cntrl/update_income" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
          <input type="text" name="track_id" value="<?php echo $track_id; ?>" > 
          <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Income Name</label>
              <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" class="span6 m-wrap" value="<?echo $name->income_name?>" name="income_name" id="income_name" readonly>
                  <?php echo form_error('income_name'); ?>        
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Income Amount</label>
              <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" class="span6 m-wrap" value="<?echo $name->income_amount?>" name="income_amount" id="income_amount" >
                  <?php echo form_error('income_amount'); ?>        
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Crop Quantity</label>
              <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" class="span6 m-wrap" value="<?echo $name->crop_quantity?>" name=crop_quantity" id="crop_quantity" >
                  <?php echo form_error('crop_quantity'); ?>        
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Per Rate</label>
              <div class="controls">
                  <input type="text" class="span6 m-wrap" value="<?echo $name->per_rate?>" name=per_rate" id="per_rate" >
                  <?php echo form_error('per_rate'); ?>        
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="control-group">
              <label class="control-label">Choose a client</label>
              <div class="controls">
                  <select class="span6 m-wrap" name="select_client" >
                      <? foreach ($client_details->result() as $var) { ?> 
                          <option <?php if($name->client_id == $var->client_id) { ?> selected="selected" <? } ?> value="<?echo $var->client_id;?>"><?echo $var->client_name;?></option>
                      <?}?>
                  </select>
                  <?php echo form_error('select_client'); ?>
              </div>
          </div>   

          <div class="form-actions">
              <button type="submit" class="btn green" id="Submit">Submit</button> 
     </form>
 <?}?>
```

**controller**

After removing the crop quantity and per rate no error but dont edit it.

```
public function update_income(){
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div style="color:#B94A48">', '</div>');                                                                                                                                                                                                   

    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('income_name', 'Income name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('income_amount', 'Income Amount', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('crop_quantity', 'Crop Quantity', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('per_rate', 'Per Rate', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('select_client', 'Client Name', 'required');


    if ( $this -> form_validation -> run() === FALSE ){
         $this->index();
    } else {
        $track_id=$this->input->post('track_id'); 
        $income_name=$this->input->post('income_name');
        $income_amount=$this->input->post('income_amount');
        $crop_quantity=$this->input->post('crop_quantity');
        $per_rate=$this->input->post('per_rate');
        $client_name=$this->input->post('select_client');
        $this->load->model('income_edit_model');
        $data = array(
            'income_name'=>$income_name,
            'income_amount'=>$income_amount,
            'crop_quantity'=>$crop_quantity,
            'per_rate'=>$per_rate,
            'client_name'=>$client_name,
        );
        $result=$this->income_edit_model->update_track_income($data,$track_id); 
        // redirect(base_url().'income', 'refresh');   
    } 
}
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters)!!

Comment: You can use `urlencode()`

Comment: how can i use urlencode()..?

Comment: `name=crop_quantity"` should be `name="crop_quantity"`- note the opening quote.

Comment: @Mudshark thank u..i fix it and working properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems:

First: Missing `<?php` open tags. Look through this and change `<?` to `<?php`

```
<select class="span6 m-wrap" name="select_client" >
    <? foreach ($client_details->result() as $var) { ?> 
        <option <?php if($name->client_id == $var->client_id) { ?> selected="selected" <? } ?> value="<?echo $var->client_id;?>"><?echo $var->client_name;?></option>
    <? } ?>
</select>
```

Second: Missing closing `</div`

```
    <div class="form-actions">
        <button type="submit" class="btn green" id="Submit">Submit</button> 
     <!-- MISSING </div> HERE -->
</form>
```