# Cannot upload image through Ajax in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am using Jquery Ajax to upload an image in Codeigniter, But the problem is the image does not get uploaded an I get alert Disallowed key Characters.Below is the model and view I am using.

> View:

```
$("#upload_course_img").on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

 $.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>upload_course_image/upload_img",
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,               
    data: new FormData(this),
        processData:false,

        success: function(data){
         alert("data:"+data);


       },
    error: function(){                      
    alert('Error while request..');
    }
   });
});

<form  method="post" id="upload_course_img" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="course_img"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" id="submit-id-submit"/> 
</form>
```

Model:

```
public function upload_img()
{
  if($this->input->post('course_img')) {  

  $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
  $config['max_size'] = '10000';
  $config['max_width']  = '1024';
  $config['max_height']  = '768';

  $this->load->library('upload', $config);

  if (!$this->upload->do_upload())
  {

  } 
  else
  {


  }
  }
}
```

Comment: add `filename` in `if (!$this->upload->do_upload('course_img'))` and check

Comment: Do you really want to do this via ajax?

Comment: Yes i want to do this via ajax

Comment: for `Disallowed key Characters` check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters

Comment: @Saty i have checked this link before but it is not working

Comment: add the your updated coding in this post

Comment: What's the actual file name you're trying to upload?

Comment: @Patrick- I am getting the filename from following code: $var = $_POST['course_img'];

  if($this->input->post('course_img')) {      
    
  $config['file_name'] = $var;

Answer (score 1):

this is another option to upload file using AJAX http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload

Answer (score 0):

Just Try Like this

```
//Program a custom submit function for the form
$("form#data").submit(function(event){

  //disable the default form submission
  event.preventDefault();

  //grab all form data  
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'formprocessing.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (returndata) {
      alert(returndata);
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to upload image using AJAX, use `Dropzone JS.` It will really make your life easy

Check out the **[Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)** Website

You just have to instantiate the `dropzonejs` object and set the options

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
      paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
      maxFilesize: 2, // MB
      accept: function(file, done) {
        if (file.name == "image.jpg") {
          done("Naha, you don't.");
        }
        else { done(); }
      }
    };
```