# it shows "Disallowed Key Characters" in chrome for all Codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter

in my local pc, i have many projects created in codeigniter. but suddently in chome it shows "Disallowed Key Characters". This shows for all CI project. However in firefox it works ok.  I dont know that why only CI not works in chrome. This is not specific to any CI PROJECT. it shows same error for all project in chrome.

what may be reason ?

Comment: what version of CI are you using ?

Comment: i am using code igniter version  2.2.4

Answer (score 3):

this issue may be caused by some input. 
You can `hack` codeigniter input.php library and accept more characters in the `preg_match`.

Just change the line 729~ of `/system/core/input.php` for this:

```
function _clean_input_keys($str)
{
    if ( ! preg_match("/^[a-z0-9:_\/-]+$/i", $str))
    {
        exit('Disallowed Key Characters.');
    }

    return $str;
}
```

You should check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters) for more information

Comment: This issue is not for specific project of CI. I have more than 20 projects  and each project shows this error. It was already working ok before. I think there should be some issue with chrome.