# How to get ajax answer in my php controller

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on a new project and it's on a nice framework which is CodeIgniter, but I got some problem when I want to use ajax (I am very bad with this). I want to get the value of a select on my controller but I don't know why (maybe because I am bad with ajax) I can't get the correct value. When I want to know what the ajax request send me it's show a boolean.

On the network app from Chrome I got the request who send the correct value which is "annee : the value of the select" but can't get it on my controller..

This is my ajax :

```
$('#annee').change(function(){
    var annee = $('#annee').val();
    console.log(annee);

    $.ajax({
        url: "admin",
        type: 'post',
        data: {annee:annee},
    })
});
```

This is my Model (cmip_model.php):

```
function getWhere($annee) {

    $query = $this->db->get_where('cmip_surcharges_go', array('annee' => 
$annee));
    return $query->result ();
}
```

This is my controller (CMIP.php):

```
public function admin()
{
    $this->load->model('cmip_model');
    $cmip_Obj = new cmip_model();
   
    $surcharges = $cmip_Obj->getWhere($this->input->post('annee'));

    $data = array();
    $data['surcharges'] = $surcharges;

    $data['page_title'] = " :: Admin";
    $data['main_content'] = 'client/CMIP/admin';
    $data['active'] = 'CMIP';
    $this->load->view('_includes/template', $data);
}
```

And this is my view :

```
  année: <select id="annee">
        <option value="">--année--</option>
        <option value="2019">2019</option>
        <option value="2020">2020</option>
        <option value="2021">2021</option>
        <option value="2022">2022</option>
        <option value="2023">2023</option>
        <option value="2024">2024</option>
    </select>
 <?php var_dump($this->input->post('annee'));
 var_dump($surcharges);
 ?>
```

Actually I got this from my var dump :

B:\wamp\www\cotationtro\applications\frontoffice\views\client\CMIP\admin.php:380:
boolean
false

Comment: Can you clarify: You are examining the output of `<?php var_dump($this->input->post('annee')); var_dump($surcharges); ?>` by looking at the Network tab of the Chrome Developer Tools, correct?

Comment: Oh no, i saw the answer directly on my page! Only looking the request of the ajax on the network tab :)

Comment: Based on information in comments on my (deleted because it was completely wrong because of misleading information elsewhere) answer, this is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197976/codeigniter-disallowed-key-characters

Comment: It's weird because the answerare just number like 2019, 2020 but i will try thanks !

Comment: i dont understand the flow here. you have a page (i guess it is not above), that makes an ajax call to the function admin and that renders a view as an ajax response? what are you trying to accomplish. step by step.

Comment: Hey @Alex, i want to send the <select> value in my controller with ajax, so the ajax get the value of the select, send it to my controller function wich is "admin" and insert in my getWhere. But it's look like my controller can't get the value of the post, but weirdly in chrome i don't have anything but in mozilla i get the value of the post but only with get..

Comment: @martingenot by "insert" i guess you don't mean in the database but rather use as a variable. i would open dev tools and go to the network pane and look for your request. see if it generates a 404 then check the answer below. further i'm  not really understanding why you are rendering a view in your ajax method. what are you planning on doing with this as i can see you don't have any logic to use the html response in your js/ajax code.

Answer (score 0):

Make changes in Ajax URL

```
url: "<?= base_url('controller_name/function_name')?>",
```

Comment: "Also, use single ' or double quotes " to declare a variable in Ajax call" — That's a property name, not a variable, and using an identifier is fine. There are no special characters in the name `annee` that would require representing it as a string in that context.

Comment: @Quentin Got it.

Comment: @Alex according to the question I post an answer. But not due to use appropriate wording (`"Also, use single ' or double quotes " to declare a variable in Ajax call"`) answer got downvoted instead of edit.